# Convert HTML to XAML

Tags: html, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to convert HTML into XAML?
I noticed that you can paste HTML into a RichTextBox and you can get the XAML by looking at the FlowDocument. However, this is a hack.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do an exact conversion from HTML to XAML, because there isn't a one to one equivalence between the two.

There are a few tools that may help you, but don't expect a perfect result :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx

http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2313.aspx

Comment: These tools are to convert XAML to HTML, not HTML TO XMAL

Comment: @Jason, you're right about the first one, but not the second: "This tool allows you to enter XAML and have it converted to HTML, *or enter HTML and have it converted to XAML*. Anyway, the OP accepted the answer...