# Newsletter in silverlight, converting xaml to html?

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, email, xaml

For my project I'm trying to create a page where my admin can send an email through the website itself. I created the following for each to send emails to each of the subscribers.

```
foreach (Inschrijvingen person in ingeschrevenen)
            {
                mailclient.SendMailAsync(person.naam, "Ondernemersaward Nieuwsbrief", person.email, "ondernemersaward@gmail.com", txtSubject.Text, txtContent.Text);
            }
```

It is then send to my email service which sends the email.

```
public Boolean SendMail(string emailFromName, string emailToName, string emailTo, string emailFrom, string msgSubject, string msgBody)
        {
            try
            {
                var fromAddress = new MailAddress(emailFrom, emailFromName);
                var toAddress = new MailAddress(emailTo, emailToName);
                const string fromPassword = "123456789oa";
                string subject = msgSubject;
                string body = msgBody;

                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
                    Timeout = 20000
                };
                using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body
                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
            }
```

This all works but my problem is that the text that is inserted into the mail is just one line of text. I would like the user to able to "position" the text a bit.

Now I know this is possible with a `richtextbox`, but that only returns `XAML`. I'm quite sure I can't send `XAML` with my email as it would be unreadable.

So I was wondering if it was possible to convert `XAML` to `HTML` in some way? Or if there is another, better way to do this?

I found one converter [here](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2313.aspx) (in another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099798/convert-html-to-xaml)), but I can't seem to get it working as it's made for a very old version of silverlight. I also found the [following msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but I can't seem to get it working either. In each of the applications I get about 255 errors.

I am hoping one of you can help me, thank you for taking the time to read this and trying to help me.
Thomas

Comment: You may have to just take one of those samples and just convert them to work with Silverlight.

Comment: I have been trying but this uses so many old controls that don't function any more, or I don't know how to get them working.

Comment: Old controls? Like what?

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, what I think you are really looking fora silver light based html editor [like this one](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/silverlightelements/controls/silverlight-html-editor).

Comment: That would be amazing, althought I don't have $699 spare to buy this ;)